# How to detect when apt-get requests cdrom?

Tags: bash, debian, apt, package-management

I'm using debian 8 jessie. I don't use a physical CD-drive, there is no `/dev/cdrom`. I have DVD-1 and DVD-2 iso files of the operating system. I mounted DVD-1 iso at `/media/cdrom01` and DVD-2 iso at `/media/cdrom02`. I used `apt-cdrom add -d /media/cdrom01` to detect DVD-1 and similarly DVD-2 mounted iso files which automatically creates entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. The entries created look like this.

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-2 20160123-19:03]/ jessie contrib main
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160123-19:03]/ jessie contrib main
```

When installing a package available from DVD-1 or DVD-2, `apt-get` determines whether the package containing disk/iso is mounted at `/media/cdrom` or not, and prompts to insert the disk when it is not mounted.  At that point the `apt-get` terminal output gives

```
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Debian GNU/Linux 8.3.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20160123-19:03'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter
```

and the `dmesg` output gives

```
[22133.506274] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[22133.506359] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
```

The problem here is `apt-get` always checks the mountpoint at `/media/cdrom` even when I used custom mountpoint when adding entries through `apt-cdrom`. With this scenario, I keep symlinking `/media/cdrom01`(or cdrom02) to `/media/cdrom`. Now the main issue is, Whenever I try to install packages contained in both DVD's , I have to manually switch the symlink.

If I use only DVD-1 iso file, it can be mounted permanently to `/media/cdrom` and packages on it can be installed easily.

Ideally, I would like to detect what DVD apt is requesting and have a script that automatically unmounts other iso and mounts the required iso at `/media/cdrom`. Is this possible?

I could also make sources.list point to a real different mountpoint like this

```
deb file:///media/cdrom01 jessie main contrib
deb file:///media/cdrom02 jessie main contrib
```

but doing so will make the packages unauthenticated, and with `http jessie` source enabled, it ignores the local packages because it thinks they are unauthenticated.

Comment: If you must have DVD ISOs in use, mount `image 1` in `cdrom01` and `image 2` in `cdrom02`, tell apt about this (`deb file:///media/cdrom01 distro main contrib` ), go on with your live.

Comment: @BinaryZebra That would make the packages unauthenticated, even though the packages are from genuine source.

Comment: Are not the packages inside the cd-rom already signed? Why would the signature be forgotten?

Comment: The packages are from official iso (md5 verified). The issue is `apt-get` expects the cdrom mountpoint at `/media/cdrom`. I can add iso mounted at custom path using `apt-cdrom` but still `apt-get` requests to mount cd to `/media/cdrom` when installing packages. It seems any mountpoint other than /media/cdrom makes the packages unauthenticated. So, I want to detect when apt-get requests cd and automate a script that symlinks appropriate mountpoint to /media/cdrom.. Thanks:)

Comment: Please take a look to [Apt-get conf file example](file:///usr/share/doc/apt/examples/configure-index.gz) there are options to define a different mount point for cd-rom. And automatic mounting of cdrom. Also relevant to [read this page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man5/apt.conf.5.html)

Comment: Also, read the [man page for apt-cdrom](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/apt-cdrom.8.html) ( apt-cdrom is used to add a new CDROM to APTs list of available sources.)

Comment: @BinaryZebra It sounds to me like you could write an answer.